# Ошибка с базой данных django

Tags: python, django, база-данных, хостинг

Я залил сайт на хостинг python anywhere и база данных перестала подключатся, при отправке get запроса вылетает ошибка unable to open database file.

settings.py:

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'home/misha123412/hairdressProject/my_site/sqlite3.db',
    }
}
```

Розположение файла вроде написано правильно.
Если нужна будет еще информация то я отпарвлю.

Comment: `'home/` — обратите внимание, что путь не абсолютный

Comment: Спасибо, поменял на /home/ и помогло!